# nvidia-pyindex installed unsuccessfully on win10

Tags: triton

I want to install `tritonclient` according to [client_libraries.md](https://github.com/triton-inference-server/server/blob/master/docs/client_libraries.md) on `win10`. Errors happened when I install `nvidia-pyindex`. How to solve it? Thanks!

```
(py38trtc250) G:\client_py>pip install --user nvidia-pyindex
Looking in indexes: https://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple
Collecting nvidia-pyindex
  Using cached https://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/packages/64/4c/dd413559179536b9b7247f15bf968f7e52b5f8c1d2183ceb3d5ea9284776/nvidia-pyindex-1.0.5.tar.gz (6.1 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: nvidia-pyindex
  Building wheel for nvidia-pyindex (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'D:\Anaconda\envs\py38trtc250\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\15151\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a7e_bahh\\nvidia-pyindex\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\15151\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a7e_bahh\\nvidia-pyindex\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\15151\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-cho7jhkv'
       cwd: C:\Users\15151\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a7e_bahh\nvidia-pyindex\
  Complete output (25 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib
  creating build\lib\nvidia_pyindex
  copying nvidia_pyindex\cmdline.py -> build\lib\nvidia_pyindex
  copying nvidia_pyindex\utils.py -> build\lib\nvidia_pyindex
  copying nvidia_pyindex\__init__.py -> build\lib\nvidia_pyindex
  running egg_info
  writing nvidia_pyindex.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to nvidia_pyindex.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing entry points to nvidia_pyindex.egg-info\entry_points.txt
  writing top-level names to nvidia_pyindex.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'nvidia_pyindex.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  writing manifest file 'nvidia_pyindex.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  installing to build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel
  running install
  '"nvidia_pyindex uninstall"' 不是内部或外部命令，也不是可运行的程序
  或批处理文件。
  error: [WinError 2] 系统找不到指定的文件。
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  COMMAND: InstallCommand
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for nvidia-pyindex
  Running setup.py clean for nvidia-pyindex
Failed to build nvidia-pyindex
Installing collected packages: nvidia-pyindex
    Running setup.py install for nvidia-pyindex ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'D:\Anaconda\envs\py38trtc250\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\15151\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a7e_bahh\\nvidia-pyindex\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\15151\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a7e_bahh\\nvidia-pyindex\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\15151\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ma8cx0c0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\15151\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Include\nvidia-pyindex'
         cwd: C:\Users\15151\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a7e_bahh\nvidia-pyindex\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    running install
    '"nvidia_pyindex uninstall"' 不是内部或外部命令，也不是可运行的程序
    或批处理文件。
    error: [WinError 2] 系统找不到指定的文件。
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    COMMAND: InstallCommand
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'D:\Anaconda\envs\py38trtc250\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\15151\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a7e_bahh\\nvidia-pyindex\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\15151\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a7e_bahh\\nvidia-pyindex\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\15151\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ma8cx0c0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\15151\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Include\nvidia-pyindex' Check the logs for full command output.
```